# Rails: How to destroy all user's posts when user is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a `SuperAdmin` who can destroy `users` and `posts`.

However, there's a problem when destroying users. Since all the user's old post still exist, there's a bunch of posts left with blank users. Errors ensue.

Would you know how to code it so that when the user is destroyed, all posts of that user are also destroyed? Here is what I'm using in the SuperAdmin controller.

```
class SuperAdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'super_admin'
  before_action :authenticate_super_admin!
end  


  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to :back, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance and for your patience. I am new to coding.

Comment: you do not have to call `@user.destroy` separately. `if @user.destroy` will do it alone.

Comment: by the way, i'm note sure what kind of site you are developing, but looks like deleting posts is not good idea (if only you really need too). there are some gems, that can delete (or mark as deleted) users, while still keeping posts, so all conversations will still remain readable. e.g. you can take a look on https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia gem.

Answer (score 7):

use the `dependent` option on the association.

here is an example of a model definition. when you delete a post, its assets will be deleted as well, as part of the dependent association:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
end
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html